Error: read ECONNRESET problem when using yarn to start a React project
when I do 'yarn start' with my project this error always occurs:
    
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

These are the possible solutions I've already tried so far :

Shut down the computer and restart (doesn't work)

lsof i:Find if the port is occupied (not occupied)

Configure the target of the proxy in webpack.dev file (tried a lot none of them works)

netstat to show the network situation (can't figure out which one because it doesn't show port number on mac)

Compare the webpack file with another local project that can be started ( they are the same)

View the activity monitor (didn't found which one)


PS: I had this project running normally two days ago, but I deleted the project and git cloned it again. And it wouldn't work now. Does this has anything to do with this ?

Now I've tried two more ways: 7. switch node version (didn't work) 8. closing some login items (didn't work either) And I've gone crazy now

This question provides almost none of the information necessary to answer it. For one, we have no idea what your start script does. For two, you mentioned you are using webpack but didn't provide the config file. Also, since it's a network error, it is quite possible the error is in your network configuration which makes this question unanswerable. Please edit the question to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example

This problem has already been solved, the reason behind this error is actually an import:
    // @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

After I deleted this line, everything worked fine.
